# Doing Pandas properly... rather than using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm just getting started with Pandas and I'm finding it hard to treat dataframes like dataframes. Every now and again, I just can't work out how to do something without iterating through rows.

For example, I've got a dataframe with budget info. I want to extract the 'vendor' from the 'short description', which is a string of one of three potential forms:

1. blah blah blah to *vendor name*
2. blah blah blah at *vendor name*
3. *vendor name*

I can do this using the following code, but I can't help but feel that it's not using Pandas properly. Any thoughts on improving it?

```
for i, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    current = dataframe['short description'][i]
    if 'to' in current:
        point_of_break = current.index('to') + 3
        dataframe['vendor'][i] = current[point_of_break:]
    elif 'at' in current:
        point_of_break = current.index('at') + 3
        dataframe['vendor'][i] = current[point_of_break:]
    else:
        dataframe['vendor'][i] = current
```

Comment: You could try using a regex - take a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html for the methods that support regexes.

Comment: Does every row contain the vendor name in quotes, or are you just using those to indicate where the vendor name falls in each string?

Comment: That's not what I meant! My fault. I'll update the original question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `to` or `at` and then select last value of list by `str[-1]`:

I implemented this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42109585/2901002).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['blah blah blah to "vendor name"',
                        'blah blah blah at "vendor name"',
                        '"vendor name"']})
print (df)

                                 A
0  blah blah blah to "vendor name"
1  blah blah blah at "vendor name"
2                    "vendor name"

print (df.A.str.split('[at|to]\s+'))
0    [blah blah blah t, "vendor name"]
1    [blah blah blah a, "vendor name"]
2                      ["vendor name"]
Name: A, dtype: object

df['vendor'] = df.A.str.split('(at|to) *').str[-1]
print (df)
                                 A          vendor
0  blah blah blah to "vendor name"   "vendor name"
1  blah blah blah at "vendor name"   "vendor name"
2                    "vendor name"   "vendor name"
```

Alternatively use:

```
df['vendor'] = df.A.str.split('[at|to]\s+').str[-1]
print (df)
                                 A         vendor
0  blah blah blah to "vendor name"  "vendor name"
1  blah blah blah at "vendor name"  "vendor name"
2                    "vendor name"  "vendor name"
```

Comment: Very nice. Probably better than my answer, because it's simpler

Comment: This looks like it works! Nice one.

Any reason why I should choose one of your solutions over the other?

Comment: It is simplier, but it is up to you. Thank you for accepting!