# Extract text with multiple separators

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have list of strings with separators `A` and `B`:

```
L = ['sgfgfqds A aaa','sderas B ffff','eeee','sdsdfd A rrr']
```

and need:

```
L1 = [['aaa'], ['ffff'], ['eeee'], ['rrr']]
```

I tried using:

```
L1 = [re.findall(r'(?<=A)(.*)$', inputtext) for inputtext in L]
print (L1)
```

but, it returns the following:

```
[[' aaa'], [], [], [' rrr']]
```

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) to break your strings on either `'A'` or `'B'`:

```
>>> L1 = [re.split(r'[AB] *', inputtext)[-1] for inputtext in L]
>>> L1
['aaa', 'ffff', 'eeee', 'rrr']
```

Comment: damn I had `LL = [re.split("[AB]",x)[-1].strip() for x in L]` :)

Comment: I think if you have `A` and `B` always enclosed with whitespaces, you'd better use `r' +[AB] +'` (or `r'\s+[AB]\s+'`).

Answer (score 6):

Alternative suggestion without `regex`.

```
[[i] for i in ' '.join(L).split(' ') if i.count(i[0]) == len(i) and len(i) > 1]
```

**Result**

```
 [['aaa'], ['ffff'], ['eeee'], ['rrr']]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the fact that `split` returns a list even if it doesn't find the separator.

```
 L1 = [[x.split(' A ')[-1].split(' B ')[-1]] for x in L]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to work with more than only A or B, you could use

```
>>> L = ['sgfgfqds A aaa','sderas B ffff','eeee','sdsdfd A rrr', 'lasjd X gggggg']
>>> L1 = [re.split(r'[A-Z] *', inputtext)[-1] for inputtext in L]
>>> print(L1)
['aaa', 'ffff', 'eeee', 'rrr', 'gggggg']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in L:
   if 'A' in a or 'B' in a:
       clist = a.split()
       for c in clist:
           if c[::-1] == c:
               if c == 'A' or c == 'B':
                    pass
                else:
                  #print "c1",c
                   result.append([c])
            else:
                 pass
   else:
       result.append([a])

   print result
```